# Filtering boolean values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter only columns with True values from this dataset:

```
Name Surname Age New_Joiner
Greta G.     56    False
Tim   H.     24    True
Rita  F.     46    False
Sara  S.     34    True
...
```

My expected output would be

```
Name Surname Age New_Joiner
Tim   H.     24    True
Sara  S.     34    True
...
```

I have tried to add this selection condition in a very small function (probably it does not make a lot of sense):

```
def filt(file):
    file[['New_Joiner']]
    return file
```

But when I call it

```
sel=filt(df)
```

I got not only True values but also False.
I checked the type of New_Joiner column using dtype and it is boolean.

Comment: What about `df[df[‘New_Joiner’]]`. (Just off the top of my head; have not tested.

Comment: Thank you so much to all of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function to

```
def filt(file):
    file = file[file['New_Joiner']]
    return file
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two steps, just

```
sel = file[file['New_Joiner']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment now that I’ve tested.  You can skip the function all together and use:

```
df[df['New_Joiner']]
```

This will only return the `True` values as it’s a boolean mask.